# 404 not found, 500 http error, con mercado pago en producción

Tags: php, mercadopago

Tengo subido un ecommerce con Mercado Pago integrado, el sitio ya esta configurado para correr sobre un `ssl` y tiene implementado el checkout basico con el `client_id`, y `client_secret` de mi cliente. 
Como sugiere el título estoy teniendo un `404 not found` (si el array consume datos de envio a domicilio), o `500 http error` (sino adquiere los datos de envio).

```
www.oesteneumaticos.com.ar
```

Les paso los dos códigos a continuación:

Con envio:

```
<?php 

require_once ("sdk-php-master-mp/lib/mercadopago.php");




if(!isset($_POST['referencia'])){
header("Location:index.php");

}


session_start();

$session = new Session();

$session->controlarTiempoDeSesion();



$_SESSION['nombre']=$_POST['nombre'];

$_SESSION['apellido']=$_POST['apellido'];

$_SESSION['tipo_dni']=$_POST['tipo_dni'];

$_SESSION['dni']=$_POST['dni'];

$_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];

$_SESSION['cod_area']=$_POST['cod_area'];

$_SESSION['telefono']=$_POST['telefono'];

$_SESSION['provincia']=$_POST['provincia'];

$_SESSION['ciudad']=$_POST['ciudad'];

$_SESSION['cp']=$_POST['cp'];

$_SESSION['calle']=$_POST['calle'];

$_SESSION['altura']=$_POST['altura'];

$_SESSION['piso']=$_POST['piso'];

$_SESSION['departamento']=$_POST['departamento'];

$_SESSION['referencia']=$_POST['referencia'];


$usuario = new Usuario();

$mp = new MP ("client_id", "client_secret");


$preference_data = array(
"items" => array(
    array(
        "title" => "Productos Cubiertas Oeste",
        "currency_id" => "ARG",
        "category_id" => "Category",
        "quantity" => 1,
        "unit_price" => (float)$usuario->mostrarTotal()
    )
),
"payer" => array(
        "name" => $_POST['nombre'],
        "surname" => $_POST['apellido'],
        "email" => $_POST['email'],
        "date_created" => date("y-m-d"),
"phone" => array(
        "area_code" => $_POST['cod_area'],
        "number" => $_POST['telefono']
),
"identification" => array(
        "type" => $_POST['tipo_dni'],
        "number" => $_POST['dni']
),
"address" => array(
    "street_name" => $_POST['calle'],
    "street_number" => (int)$_POST['altura'],
    "zip_code" => $_POST['cp']
)
),
"shipments" => array(
    "receiver_address" => array(
        "zip_code" => $_POST['cp'],
        "street_number"=> (int)$_POST['altura'],
        "street_name"=> $_POST['calle'],
        "floor"=> (int)$_POST['piso'],
        "apartment"=> $_POST['departamento']
        )
    ),
"auto_return"=>"approved",
"back_urls" => array(
    "success" => "http://www.oesteneumaticos.com.ar/landing.php",
    "failure" => "http://www.oesteneumaticos.com.ar/landing-error.php",
    "pending" => "http://www.oesteneumaticos.com.ar/landing.php"
),
    "external_reference" => "".$_POST['referencia'].""


);


$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);




?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
...

    <script src="https://secure.mlstatic.com/sdk/javascript/v1/mercadopago.js"></script>


</head>

<body>



...



<a id="pago-btn" href="<?php echo $preference["response"]["init_point"]; ?>"mp-mode="modal" onreturn="execute_my_onreturn" onClick="registrarUsuario('<?php echo $_POST['nombre']?>','<?php echo $_POST['apellido']?>','<?php echo $_POST['tipo_dni']?>','<?php echo $_POST['dni']?>','<?php echo $_POST['email']?>','<?php echo $_POST['cod_area']?>','<?php echo $_POST['telefono']?>','<?php echo $_POST['provincia']?>','<?php echo $_POST['ciudad']?>','<?php echo $_POST['cp']?>','<?php echo $_POST['calle']?>','<?php echo $_POST['altura']?>','<?php echo $_POST['piso']?>','<?php echo $_POST['departamento']?>','<?php echo $_POST['referencia'] ?>');"  name="MP-Checkout"class="carrito-checkout-btn">Pagar</a>




...



<script type="text/javascript">


(function(){function $MPC_load(){window.$MPC_loaded !== true && (function(){var s = document.createElement("script");s.type = "text/javascript";s.async = true;s.src = document.location.protocol+"//secure.mlstatic.com/mptools/render.js";var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);window.$MPC_loaded = true;})();}window.$MPC_loaded !== true ? (window.attachEvent ?window.attachEvent('onload', $MPC_load) : window.addEventListener('load', $MPC_load, false)) : null;})();

</script>



</body>

</html>
```

Sin envio:

```
<?php 
require_once ("sdk-php-master-mp/lib/mercadopago.php");

...


if(!isset($_POST['referencia'])){
header("Location:index.php");
}


session_start();
$session = new Session();
$session->controlarTiempoDeSesion();

$usuario = new Usuario();

$_SESSION['nombre']=$_POST['nombre'];
$_SESSION['apellido']=$_POST['apellido'];
$_SESSION['tipo_dni']=$_POST['tipo_dni'];
$_SESSION['dni']=$_POST['dni'];
$_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['cod_area']=$_POST['cod_area'];
$_SESSION['telefono']=$_POST['telefono'];
$_SESSION['referencia']=$_POST['referencia'];

$mp = new MP ("client_id", "client_secret");


$preference_data = array(
    "items" => array(
        array(
        "title" => "Productos Cubiertas Oeste",
        "currency_id" => "ARG",
        "category_id" => "Category",
        "quantity" => 1,
        "unit_price" => (float)$usuario->mostrarTotal()
    )
),
"payer" => array(
        "name" => $_POST['nombre'],
        "surname" => $_POST['apellido'],
        "email" => $_POST['email'],
        "date_created" => date("y-m-d"),
"phone" => array(
        "area_code" => $_POST['cod_area'],
        "number" => $_POST['telefono']
),
),
"identification" => array(
        "type" => $_POST['tipo_dni'],
        "number" => $_POST['dni']
),
"auto_return"=>"all",
"back_urls" => array(
    "success" => "http://www.oesteneumaticos.com.ar/landing.php",
    "failure" => "http://www.oesteneumaticos.com.ar/landing-error.php",
    "pending" => "http://www.oesteneumaticos.com.ar/landing.php"
),
    "external_reference" => "".$_POST['referencia'].""

);

$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);



?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
....

    <script src="https://secure.mlstatic.com/sdk/javascript/v1/mercadopago.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

....
                   <a id="pago-btn" href="<?php echo $preference["response"]["init_point"]; ?>"mp-mode="modal" onreturn="execute_my_onreturn" onClick="registrarUsuarioSinEnvio('<?php echo $_POST['nombre']?>','<?php echo $_POST['apellido']?>','<?php echo $_POST['tipo_dni']?>','<?php echo $_POST['dni']?>','<?php echo $_POST['email']?>','<?php echo $_POST['cod_area']?>','<?php echo $_POST['telefono']?>','<?php echo $_POST['referencia'] ?>');"  name="MP-Checkout"class="carrito-checkout-btn">Pagar</a>



<script type="text/javascript"     src="//resources.mlstatic.com/mptools/render.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){function $MPC_load(){window.$MPC_loaded !== true && (function()    {var s = document.createElement("script");s.type = "text/javascript";s.async =     true;s.src = document.location.protocol+"//secure.mlstatic.com/mptools/render.js";var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);window.$MPC_loaded = true;})();}window.$MPC_loaded !== true ? (window.attachEvent ?window.attachEvent('onload', $MPC_load) : window.addEventListener('load', $MPC_load, false)) : null;})();
</script>


</body>
</html>
```